# How can I access an object (e.g. ArrayList) from another class?

Tags: java, android, class, object, android-activity

I am looking for a way that allows me access an object from another class; *both classes are  within the same Android activity* - OpenStreeMapActivity.java.  I have:

ItemizedOverlay.java - Contains the object I want to access and modify:

```
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
```

BalloonOverlayView.java - Is where I want to access the object mOverlays:

```
    protected void setupView(final Context context, final ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.balloon_overlay, parent);
    title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_item_title);
    snippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_item_snippet);

    // Get ballon_close button and register its listener:
    ImageView close = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_close);
    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            parent.setVisibility(GONE); 

            Intent intent = new Intent( );
            intent.setClassName( "org.example.openstreetmap", "org.example.openstreetmap.UpdateEntityActivity" );
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            //HERE I return from UpdateOverlayActivity.java and is where I want to modify *mOverlays*.
        }
    });

}
```

**Edit:** I figured out that it is not true that I return to //HERE.

Comment: can't you pass the object mOverlays as parameter of method setupView? if not, you can still assign it to a public property of the BalloonOverlayView class before setupView is called, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `BalloonOverlayView` hold a reference to a list of `OverlayItem` object this way:

```
public class BalloonOverlayView{
 List<OverlayItem> items = null;
 public BalloonOverlayView(List<OverlayItem> items){
    this.items = items;
 }
 // Now you can use the ItemizedOverlay class from within this class as you wish
 public void addItem(OverlayItem item){
    items.add(item);
 }
 public void removeItem(OverlayItem item){
    item.remove(item);
 }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestions give me the items `(e.g. items.getItem() )` but it does not allow me to do things like `items.add(overlay)` or `items.remove(inDrag)`.

Comment: I added `public void addItem(Item item) { items.add(item); }` but now I am getting an error that says: "The method add(Item) is undefined for the type ItemizedOverlay".

Comment: @kako13 Glad it worked, please don't forget +1 and accept this as an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 3):

In ItemizedOverlay, create a method that provides the object.

```
public List<OverlayItem> getOverlays() {
  return this.mOverlays;
}
```

Better if you use the List so, if in the future you want to change the implementation it does not affect your code elsewhere.

Comment: You are suggesting me change Arraylist for List? How I do call getOverlays in the other class?

Comment: this.mOverlays can still be an ArrayList. But when exposing the data, specifying it as a more generic superclass/interface allows you to replace it easier if needed (if you at some point decide to use your own implementation of List instead of arraylist, no changes outside ItemizedOverlay are needed). Regarding the other question, obviously you'll need to get the reference to the object you want to call; you will need to pass the reference to the calling class in a similar fashion. This is basic Java, if you have difficult with it test it with a basic console program before getting in android

Comment: you are right, `private List<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();` is prefered over `private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();`. Also, I get that, I should have a reference to the object I want to manipulate from the other class. Thanks. BTW, I like you nick name, it remember me San Juan, PR.